# Bad return type in lambda expression: Mono<User> cannot be converted to Mono<UserDetails>

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

Why does this work

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            Mono<UserDetails> userDetailsMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username));
            return userDetailsMono.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
        };
    }
```

but this doesn't (which I would prefer as a more concise option)?

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> Mono.justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
    }
```

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: Mono<User> cannot be converted to Mono<UserDetails>
```

`User` is my custom user class that implements `UserDetails`. `findByUsername()` returns `Mono<User>`

```java
// @Entity etc.
public class User implements UserDetails {
```

```java
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, UUID> {
//...
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- `ReactiveUserDetailsService`'s abstract method, `findByUsername(String username)`, returns `Mono<UserDetails>`. *Go figure why it doesn't return `Mono<? extends UserDetails>`*. It means your lambda should return `Mono<UserDetails>` too
- `Mono.justOrEmpty()` is generic and has this contract: `<T> Mono<T> justOrEmpty(@Nullable Optional<? extends T> data)`. It relies on Java's type inference which has its limitations
- When you write this code:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> Mono.justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username));
    }
```

the actual return type of `justOrEmpty()` is inferred from the return type of the wrapping function, `fetchByUsername()`. Which is `Mono<UserDetails>`

- When you write this code:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            Mono<UserDetails> userDetailsMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username));
            return userDetailsMono.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
        };
    }
```

the actual return type of `justOrEmpty()` is inferred from the type of the variable you assign the result to. Which is, again, `Mono<UserDetails>`. Inferring from an expected return type and a variable type are two the most common ways Java's type inference works for generic methods

- When you write this code

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> Mono.justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
    }
```

Java can infer `justOrEmpty()`'s return type neither from the return type of the outer function (you don't return the result of `justOrEmpty()`) nor a variable type (you don't assign the result of `justOrEmpty()`). So Java assumes the actual return type to be equal to the return type of the invoked function, `findByUsername()`. Which is `Optional<User>` (not `Optional<UserDetails>`)

- `switchIfEmpty()` doesn't change the type of `Mono`, it stays `Mono<User>`. So in the end the lambda returns `Mono<User>` which is different from `Mono<UserDetails>` that the lambda should return
- `Mono<User>` is not a subtype of `Mono<UserDetails>` even though `User` is a subtype of `UserDetails` (Java's generics are [invariant](https://jarombek.com/blog/may-13-2018-generics-arrays-complexities-java))
- You can also tell Java explicitly what type `justOrEmpty()` should return, sort of "turning off" the type inference. This works too:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> Mono.<UserDetails>justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
    }
```